# Gaming performance difference when played using HDMI

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, performance, hdmi, gaming

I just found out that the game that lags on my laptop works fine when connected to TV over HDMI. Driver softwares are updated properly. I'm using Windows 7. Any thoughts?

System Configuration:
Intel Core i7 2670 QM, 8GB RAM, SSD
Intel HD 3000 Integrated Graphics
Geforce GT 540M 2GB GPU

Display Configuration:
15.6" (39.6cm) FHD (1920x1080) B+RGLED display with TrueLife(TM), 60 Hz

Comment: Intel HD 3000 is not for games anyway. That combined with probably a laggy panel may explain the poor results. It also depends on what scaling that's happening in the internal monitor vs external.

Comment: What about Geforce GT 540?

Comment: Is there any way i can make the internal monitor perform as good as the other one?

Comment: Nvidia Geforec GT540 is better for games but not by much. It's old and underpowered. Also not included in the original configuration you posted, how exactly it comes to the discussion, and why? Do you have hybrid graphics? If so, you certainly should be using the Nvidia for gaming.

Comment: *Is there any way i can make the internal monitor perform as good as the other one?* No.

Comment: Sorry, geforce was missed from the list and yes its a hybrid gpu.